# Unity: How do I stop reading the first touch when using TouchPhase.Moved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have two scripts one is a player controller with this:

```
void Update () {
   if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {


        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
        {
            return;
        }


        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {

            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
             if (interactable != null)
             {
                SetFocus(interactable);
             }
             else
             {
                motor.MoveToPoint(hit.point);

                RemoveFocus();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then my camera script is:

```
void Update()
{
    currentZoom -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;
    currentZoom = Mathf.Clamp(currentZoom, minZoom, maxZoom);

    currentYaw -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * yawSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 touchDirection = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        if (touchDirection.x > minSwipe || touchDirection.x < -minSwipe)
        {
            currentYaw -= touchDirection.x * yawSpeed / mobileYawReduction * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    transform.position = target.position - offset * currentZoom;
    transform.LookAt(target.position + Vector3.up * pitch);

    transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, currentYaw);
}
```

Both of these work fine: I can move my character with a tap and rotate the camera nicely when swiping the only problem is that when I swipe to rotate it registers the start of the touch and starts moving. how would I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving when touch starts you could only move when touch ends instead and touch position wasn't changed to much during the touch.

If is touching and position changes more than a little threshold instead interpret it as swipe and skip calling the target code block when the touch ends.

```
// if movement was greater than interpret as swipe 
public float swipeThreshold = 0.01;

Vector2 startPosition ;
float movedDistance;

Touch touch;

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.touchCount <= 0) return;

    switch(Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            // On begin only save the start position

            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
            {
                return;
            }

            startPosition = touch.position;
            movedDistance = 0;
            break;

        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            // if moving check how far you moved

            movedDistance = Vector2.Distance(touch.position, startPosition );
            break;

        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            // on end of touch (like button up) check the distance
            // if you swiped -> moved more than swipeThreshold
            // do nothing

            if(movedDistance > swipeThreshold) break;

            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) break;

            Interactable interactable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (interactable != null)
            {
                SetFocus(interactable);
            }
            else
            {
                motor.MoveToPoint(hit.point);
                RemoveFocus();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I than would add the same threshold to the camera script to be consistent. Either share this threshold value somehow between them (or even get it from another script) or simply put in the same value

```
public float swipeThreshold = 0.01;

Vector2 startPosition;

void Update()
{
    currentZoom -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;
    currentZoom = Mathf.Clamp(currentZoom, minZoom, maxZoom);

    currentYaw -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * yawSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.touchCount <= 0) return;

    switch(Input.GetTouch(0).phase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            startPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            break;

        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            // if yet not moved enough do nothing
            var movedDistance = Vector2.Distance(Input.GetTouch(0).position, startPosition);
            if (movedDistance <= swipeThreshold) break;

            Vector2 touchDirection = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
            if (touchDirection.x > minSwipe || touchDirection.x < -minSwipe)
            {
                currentYaw -= touchDirection.x * yawSpeed / mobileYawReduction * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```